# How do you fetch an object from MySQL that contains a property with a value of another object in Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a few models that has relationship to each other within this object I am tryin to save and fetch from the database, but I can't seem to get it to work properly. The object contains a property that also contains another object. My approach was to save to all related models and for those models, I would also save this current model to them as well so it shows relation on the database table.

Below the models for the app.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "daily_entry")
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DailyEntry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "daily_entry_id", unique = true)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private LocalDate date;
    private int weight;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "daily_macros_id", unique = true)
    private DailyMacros dailyMacros;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dailyEntry", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Exercise> exercise = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "daily_macros")
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DailyMacros {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "daily_macros_id")
    private Long id;
    private int calories;
    private int protein;
    private int fat;
    private int carbs;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "dailyMacros", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private DailyEntry dailyEntry;
}
```

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name= "exercises")
public class Exercise {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "exercise_id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int sets;
    private int reps;
    private int weight;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "daily_entry_id", unique = true)
    private DailyEntry dailyEntry;
}
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    private String role = "user";
    private String token;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected String username;
    @Column(unique = true ,nullable = false)
    private String emailAddress;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "macros_goal_id")
    private MacrosGoal macrosGoal;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<DailyEntry> dailyEntry = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Im tryin to save the model of DailyEntry to the database.
User is the owner of DailyEntry
DailyEntry owns MacrosGoal (@OneToOne) and Exercise (@OneToMany). How exactly can I save and fetch this model into the database?

This is what I've tried -
For my PutMapping, I get this error : Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

My GetMapping just returns a empty response although http status code 200

DailyEntryController file

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DailyEntryController {

    @Autowired
    DailyEntryService dailyEntryService;

    @GetMapping("/getDailyEntry")
    public ResponseEntity<DailyEntry> getDailyEntry(@RequestParam("username")  String username, @RequestParam String date) throws ResponseStatusException {
        DailyEntry dailyEntry = dailyEntryService.getDailyEntry(username, date);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dailyEntry, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/addDailyEntry")
    public ResponseEntity<DailyEntry> addDailyEntry(@RequestBody DailyEntry dailyEntry, @RequestParam("username") String username) throws ResponseStatusException {
        DailyEntry dailyEntryInfo = dailyEntryService.createDailyEntry(dailyEntry, username);
        return new ResponseEntity<>( dailyEntryInfo, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DailyEntryServiceImpl implements DailyEntryService {

    @Autowired
    DailyEntryRepository dailyEntryRepository;
    @Autowired
    ExerciseRepository exerciseRepository;
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    DailyMacrosRepository dailyMacrosRepository;

    @Override
    public DailyEntry addExercise(Exercise exercise) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DailyEntry getDailyEntry(String username, String date) {
        DailyEntry entry = null;
        Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        User user = userFromDatabase.get();


        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
        List<DailyEntry> dailyEntryList =  user.getDailyEntry();


        for(DailyEntry e : dailyEntryList) {
            if(e.getDate() == localDate){
                entry = e;
            }
        }

        return entry;
        
    }


    @Override
    public DailyEntry createDailyEntry(DailyEntry dailyEntry, String username) {
        DailyEntry entry = new DailyEntry();
        // Find user
        Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        User user = userFromDatabase.get();

        entry.setUser(user);
        entry.setDate(LocalDate.parse(dailyEntry.getDate().toString()));
        entry.setDailyMacros(dailyEntry.getDailyMacros());
        entry.setWeight(dailyEntry.getWeight());
        entry.setExercise(dailyEntry.getExercise());

        DailyMacros dailyMacros = dailyEntry.getDailyMacros();
        dailyMacros.setDailyEntry(entry);
        dailyMacrosRepository.save(dailyMacros);

        List<Exercise> exercise = dailyEntry.getExercise();
        for (Exercise e : exercise) {
            e.setDailyEntry(entry);
            exerciseRepository.save(e);
        }

        List<DailyEntry> dailyEntryList = user.getDailyEntry();
        dailyEntryList.add(entry);
        user.setDailyEntry(dailyEntryList);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return entry;
    }
```

I also tried with Query inside repository, but I may have done it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add `@Transactional` to `createDailyEntry`.
I don't really understand what's happening in `createDailyEntry` but I think it should look something like this:

```java
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public DailyEntry createDailyEntry(DailyEntry dailyEntry, String username) {
       User user = userRepository
            .findByUsername(username)
            .get();

       dailyEntryRepository.save(dailyEntry);

       user.getDailyEntry().add(dailyEntry);
       dailyEntry.setUser(User);

        DailyMacros dailyMacros = dailyEntry.getDailyMacros();
        dailyMacros.setDailyEntry(dailyEntry);
        dailyMacrosRepository.save(dailyMacros);
 
        dailyEntry.getExcercise()
            .forEach( e -> {
                e.setDailyEntry(dailyEntry);
                exerciseRepository.save(e);
            });
        // I don't think you need this because user is already managed
        // and userFromDatabase.get() will throw an exception
        // if the user does not exist.
        // userRepository.save(user);

        return dailyEntry;
    }
```

I think `getDailyEntry` doesn't work because you are using `e.getDate() == localDate` and it's always going to be `false`.

One solution is to add a method to the DailyEntryRepository that accept `username` and `date`:

```java
    interface DailyEntryRepository extends JpaRepository<DailyEntry, Long> {
        @Query("select de from DailyEntry de where de.user.username = :username and de.date = :localDate")
        DailyEntry findByUsernameAndDate(@Param("username") String username, @Param("localDate") LocalDate date);
    }

    ...


    @Override
    public DailyEntry getDailyEntry(String username, String date) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
        return dailyEntryRepository.findByUsernameAndDate(username, localdate);
    }
```

This solution will run a query and load only the entry you need.

But, if you need to validate the username, this should work:

```java
    @Override
    public DailyEntry getDailyEntry(String username, String date) {
        User user = userRepository
            .findByUsername(username)
            .get();

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
        for(DailyEntry e : user.getDailyEntry()) {
            if (localDate.equals(e.getDate)){
                // No need to continue the loop, you've found the entry
                return entry;
            }
        }

        // daily entry not found
        return null;
    }
```

Another thing that's missing is that in your model you are not handling the bidirectional association during convertion to JSON.
The solution is to use I end up using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` where you have the association.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out. I did went with the attempt on the query in the repository, but I will try that again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question

Comment: Because you are loading the user from  the db, it's managed by the Hibernate session. This means that changes will propagate to the db automatically. In theory, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: For createDailyEntry, if it only have
`dailyEntryRepository.save(dailyEntry); return dailyEntry;` , the database for DailyEntry table, the foreign key of user_id is empty. In the exercise table, the foreign key daily_entry_id is empty as well.

Comment: This is the JSON 
{
    "date": "2022-10-30",
    "weight":1,
    "dailyMacros":{
        "protein":121211,
        "carbs":21212,
        "fat":121212,
        "calories":121211
    },
    "exercise":[{
        "name":"work out",
        "sets":12121,
        "reps":2121211,
        "weight":122120
    }]
}

Comment: I've updated my answer with I think createDailyEntry should look like. But I haven't tested it

Comment: From your updated answer, I moved your  `dailyEntryRepository.save(dailyEntry);` to after `dailyEntry.setUser(User);`. But your updated code is very similar to what I had, just without a new instance(I did try it without a new instance previously as well, but same result) and I did end up getting the same error.

Comment: It shouldn’t make a difference. What’s the exact error?

Comment: On postman, I get Could not get response, error aborted. On the IDE, it shows `Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed`

Comment: `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: `

Comment: That error happens because of the d bidirectional association when the conversion to JSON happens

Comment: You need to add an annotation to the mapping. I don’t remember right now which one, I will check later

Comment: But it has nothing to do with the methods

Comment: I added @JsonIgnore and it solved that problem, although I think I wont get a response if I use this annotation, so I may need to find an alternative, but that same method, it says it cannot invoke because dailyMacros is null, but that property is passed in as part of the object

Comment: Where did you add `@JsonIgnore`?  Based on the example JSON, dailyMacros cannot be null

Comment: You need to make sure that you have all value initialized correctly. Anyway, now you know what to look for. Good luck

Comment: Seems like it was because I added the JsonIgnore to DailyMacros and thats why it was null. Anyways. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you should use `JsonIgnoreProperties("parent")` on the collections

Comment: I end up using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`

Comment: Even better. I will add a note in my answer